# Django got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a phonebook in Django.
My urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.people_list, name='people_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d)/$', views.person_detail, name='person_detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def people_list(request):
    people = Person.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'phonebook/person/list.html', {'people': people})


def person_detail(request, person):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, id=person)
    return render(request, 'phonebook/person/detail.html', {'person': person})
```

from models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('phonebook:person_detail', args=[self.id])
```

and list.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Phonebook</h1>
{% for person in people %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{ person.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ person.name }} {{ person.last_name }}
    </a>
</h2>
<p class="where">
{{ person.department }}, {{ person.facility }}
    </p>
{{ person.phone1 }}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The index looks ok but when I try click on links to get person_detail site I get this message:

> TypeError at /phonebook/4/
>   person_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
>   Request Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/phonebook/4/ Django Version:  1.9.6
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   person_detail() got an
>   unexpected keyword argument 'id'

I have and 'id' argument in urls.py and in function to get_absolute_url. I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your parameter `?P<id>` in the URL mapping has to match the arguments in the view `def person_detail(request, person):`

They should both be `id` or both `person`.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with this.

Answer (score 11):

You should fix the view and use the `id` argument name instead of `person`:

```
def person_detail(request, id):
```

Comment: I changed id to person in urls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was I only added the first parameter instead of both,i.e I mentioned `def person_detail(request)` instead of `def person_detail(request,id)`