# TypeError at /blog/21- detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blog_id'

Tags: python, django

I'm making a tool for my project. My final objective is when I type a title, body in the `new.html` page, it works through `create.html` and finally, gets all of the information from `new.html` into the `detail.html` page. I created two apps, `Good` (writing works) and `Account` (sign in works), but I'm getting this error and can't find any solutions:

> detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blog_id'

I run this in Visual Studio Code, and I'm now trying to insert:

```
def detail(request):
    details = get_object(Good, pk= blog_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'details':details})
```

---

What do I have to do after this if it's right?

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block contents %}
<body>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
import good.views
import account.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', good.views.home, name="home"),
    path('login/', account.views.login, name="login"),
    path('signup/', account.views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('new/', good.views.new, name="new"),
    path('create/', good.views.create, name="create"),
    path('blog/<int:blog_id>', good.views.detail, name="detail"),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Good(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Good

admin.site.register(Good)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Good
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def new(request):
    return render(request, 'new.html')

def create(request):
    blog = Good()
    blog.title = request.GET['title']
    blog.body = request.GET['body']
    blog.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
    blog.save()
    return redirect('/blog/' + str(blog.id))    

def detail(request):
    blogs = Good.objects
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'blogs':blogs})
```

**new.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block contents %}
<body>
<br>
<div class="container">
<form action="{% url 'create' %}">
  <h4>title: </h4>
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4>body: </h4>
  <textarea cols=40 rows=10 name="body"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block contents %}
<body>
{% for blog in blogs.all %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ blog.pub_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ blog.body }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When you define the `detail` view you need to define it like such: `def detail(request, blog_id):` if you want to pass blog_id as an argument captured from the URL, otherwise the view function will receive it and won't be expecting it, leading to the error you're describing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254829/django-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-id)

Comment: As your advice, I added <!-- def detail(request, blog_id):
    details = get_object_or_404(Good, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'detils':details}) --> this. But nothings seem appeared in detail.html page, but not errors occured. Can you also help me for fixing detail.html page?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57242504/edit) to reflect the new version of your `detail` view, as you have two different versions in your question, one with `blogs` and the other with `details` being passed to the template in the `render` context. Also, if you have a typo such as `detils`, it won't work. Please copy and paste the code so that we can see exactly what you have, with correct formatting and no typos.

Comment: thank you a lot for helping me! Since I adjusted all the code, it doesn’t seemed other errors appeared. But, still when nothing(including the title, pub_date, body that I typed on new.html page) printed in detail.html page. Do I have to make any codes correct again?

Comment: It could be caused by a number of issues, so to isolate it please update your code in your question by editing it to the current code you have. You should also try to check if you're actually successfully saving any `Good` objects to your database by querying it or using a debugger to see what's going on as you step through the flow of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `blog_id` as the parameter to the detail function like this:

**EDIT:**
If you want to display all the objects in you detail page then you can do like this:

```
def detail(request,blog_id):
    all_objects = Good.objects.all()
    details = get_object_or_404(Good, pk= blog_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'details':details,'all_objects':all_objects})
```

Now in the template you don't need to use for loop to get the details since you are trying to get the details of only some particular id.

For example you can get the detail of that particular id like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block contents %}
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ details.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ details.pub_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ details.body }}</p>
</div>
</body>


# To get all the objects in your template try this:

{% for object in all_objects %}
<p>{{object.title}}</p>
<p>{{obj.pub_date}}<.p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I want to see all of writings that I wrote, then what do I have to change?

Comment: Did you mean the all objects that you have created ??

Comment: yes, i want to let them all appeared in the detail page. I thought my codes would do that role, but only one  article in one blog/<int:blog_id> url appears. What should I do?

Comment: OMG!! I'm so happy for your help. IT WORKED!! Thank you a lot for your kindness!!